# Check the current time concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency

I am creating an program in java and I want to check the current time each minute and if it is equal to specific time for example 10am  println("It is 10 am do this"). So far I am getting the current time like this

```
public static String RemindMe() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));

        if (dateFormat.format(date).equals("2013/03/08 11:19"))
            System.out.println("equal");
        else
            System.out.println("not equal");

        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

but how can I make it check the current time every minute and if possible concurrently. Thanks

Comment: .... You're doing this the 'hard' way (well, at least you're using a new formatter each time, which is good).  [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) and its support classes (like [LocalDateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html)) should make this more intuitive.  For instance, I've been assuming that timezone shouldn't matter, but it might.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
final Runnable checkTime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        remindMe();
    }
};
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkTime, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Note: the convention in Java is to start method names in lower case.

Comment: don't think its an acceptable solution. For illustration, if the frequency is 1 hour rather than 1 minute, this solution can trigger remindMe() at 9:35, 10:35 and so on. But as per requirement it must trigger at 9:00, 10:00 etc.

Comment: @sgp15 If it needs to run at a specific time, the initial delay needs to be adjusted. I'm not clear if that is the case.

Comment: @JBNizet - 1 hour was just for illustration. The idea is to generate triggers at minute boundaries.

Comment: I misread the answer. I would just start the scheduler immediately, and make it check the current tume every minute.

Comment: @assylias - its like this. scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkTime, 60 - ((60 + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND)) % 60), 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

Comment: @sgp15 You are mixing seconds and minutes there but I get the idea.

Comment: @assylias - my bad. This should be good. scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(checkTime, 60 - ((60 + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND)) % 60), 60, TimeUnit.SECOND);